# Count number of cases where visitor rank is higher on one page then on another

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to count number `fullvisitorID` where rank in `/page_y` is higher then rank in `page_x`. So in this case result would be 1, only `111`

| fullvisitorID | rank | page |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | /page_x |
| 111 | 2 | /page_y |
| 222 | 1 | /page_x |
| 222 | 2 | /page_x |
| 333 | 2 | /page_x |
| 333 | 1 | /page_y |

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the below approach:

```
select count(*) from (
  select distinct fullvisitorID
  from your_table
  qualify max(if(page='/page_y',rank,null)) over win > max(if(page='/page_x',rank,null)) over win
  window win as (partition by fullvisitorID)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT COUNTIF(page = '/page_y') cnt FROM (
  SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE page IN ('/page_x', '/page_y')
 QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fullvisitorID ORDER BY rank DESC) = 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

for count you can use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT fullvisitorID, COUNT(fullvisitorID), Page FROM table t1
WHERE rank = (SELECT MAX(t2.rank) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.fullvisitorID = t1.fullvisitorID)
Group By fullvisitorID, Page
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the response but this returns all unique fullVisitorIDs with highest rank. So in table above it would return also 222 with value /page_x and 333 with value /page_x

Comment: some time it's hard understand, can you provide expected output in table form

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a `SELF JOIN` between the two tables, by matching on the "*fullvisitorID*" field, then force

- the first table to have "*page_y*" values
- the second table to have "*page_x*" values
- rank of the first table to have higher rank of the second table

```
SELECT *
FROM       tab t1
INNER JOIN tab t2
        ON t1.fullvisitorID = t2.fullvisitorID
       AND t1.page = '/page_y'
       AND t2.page = '/page_x'
       AND t1.rank > t2.rank
```

Comment: hi, rank just for an example has two values. It can have 100+ values where e.g. 33 are page_y and 67 are page_x

Answer (score 0):

Table separation approach:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE ( fullvisitorID INT, [rank] INTEGER,[page] VARCHAR (max)) --here where page = x
DECLARE @t2 TABLE ( fullvisitorID INT, [rank] INTEGER,[page] VARCHAR (max)) --here where page = y 
INSERT INTO @t1 SELECT * FROM @test t WHERE t.[page] LIKE '/page_x'
 INSERT INTO @t2 SELECT * FROM @test t WHERE t.[page] LIKE '/page_y'
          
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t1 INNER JOIN @t2 ON [@t1].fullvisitorID = [@t2].fullvisitorID WHERE [@t1].rank < [@t2].rank
```